How to uncomment django html comments?
In VSCode ctrl + / comments out  code and usually the same shortcut is used to uncomment.
{% extends 'master.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
  {% crispy form %}
{% endblock %} {% endcomment %}


however:
{% comment %} {% comment %} {% extends 'master.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
  {% crispy form %}
{% endblock %} {% endcomment %} {% endcomment %}


Any work arounds or extensions that addresses this?
I looked for any django specific extensions and did a search online.
I saw a few issues listed about the shortcut not working.
I was hoping someone else has stumbled upon a work around?
Option 1 - Search for the comment and delete
Option 2 - Delete with multiple cursors
But... Hoping someone else found a better way.
